# Error: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider> while using redux toolkit in new nextjs 13.4

Tags: next.js, react-redux, redux-toolkit

Actually i'm new to nextjs 13.4 and i want to use redux toolkit with my application
But im getting error while doing this.
I wrapped the Provider to the parent component but still the component not getting the redux values

Here the code

Store.js

```
'use client';

import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import balanceReducer from './features/balance/balanceSlice';


export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        balance: balanceReducer
    }
})
```

Provider.js

```
'use client';
import { store } from "./store";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";


export function Providers({ children }) {
    return <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>

}
```

layout.js

```
import Navbar from "@/components/Navbar";
import "./globals.css";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import { Providers } from "./redux/provider";


const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata = {
  title: "Money Tracker - A money management solution",
  description: "",
};

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <Providers>
          <Navbar />
          {children}
        </Providers>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

page.js

```
import { addBalance, cutBalance } from "./redux/features/balance/balanceSlice";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
export default function Home() {
  const balance = useSelector((state) => state.balance.value)
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  return (
    <>
      {balance}
    </>
  );
}
```

I tried wrapping the children but still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

My environment:  "next": "^13.4.8",, "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",

Hey there! I ran into the same issue. I believe what is going on in your code is that you are not putting:

'use client';

at the top of your page.js

similarly  wherever you are going to use:

import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'

you need to put 'use client'; at the top of your file because the context at that point without it is server side because of the nature of NextJS. You'll need this for example later you will develop routed and some nested pages and need to access the redux state.

How I found out:
I was dealing with the same error and tried wrapping that dang provider everywhere getting the same error! I finally console.log'ed the store and got the result server side and it clicked!